# Discrete Topology has NO limit points

Tags: general-topology, definition

So I'm pretty frustrated right now because I just found out that the discrete topology has no limit points. We all know how the proof goes. Informally, it's something like this.

Let $(\mathbb{X},\tau)$ be a topological space with the discrete topology. This is to say that $\tau = P(\mathbb{X}).$

Consider any $x \in X.$ Since $\tau$ is the discrete topology, $\{x\} \in \tau$ for all $x\in \mathbb{X}$

Then $\tau$ has no limit points because $\{x\} \backslash \{x\} = \emptyset$. Limit points require that *all* subsets containing $x$ intersect with some other value other than $x$. Therefore, $(\mathbb{X},\tau)$ has no limit points.

---

So this is incredibly frustrating. Why? Because every other possible set containing $x$ is going to have points other than $x$ in it as well. $\{x\}$ is the *only* case where $x$ is not a limit point. Why can't we just modify our definition of limit points to give us non-trivial results?

For example, $\{x\} \backslash \{x\} = \emptyset$ is a trivial result. Can't we just say $x$ is a limit point in the discrete topology in all subsets of $\mathbb{X}$ except in its own singleton? What's wrong with doing that?

Comment: $x$ being a limit point informally means that $x$ can be approach arbitrarily close by other elements. Such thing cannot happen in discrete topology, where every point is isolated.

Comment: @freakish what if $\mathbb{X}$ was found to be metrizable? Then, could we approach arbitrarily close to other elements?

Comment: No, you cannot approach isolated points arbitrarily close. That's actually what "being isolated" means. In any space, metric or not. For example consider the discrete metric $d(x,y)=1$ for $x\neq y$. Then only $x_0$ satisfies $d(x_0,x)\leq 1/2$, every point is isolated. The discrete topology is always metrizable btw.

Comment: The whole point of a limit point is to distinguish between points that are isolated (and where limits are basically useless as a notion) and the other points that *can* be approached by other points and where limits of functions are meaningful ideas (hence the name, presumably). In a discrete space everything trivialises (all functions are continuous) so there’s nothing to be frustrated about at all IMO.